# Service Error: Spreadsheets (getLastRow)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am at my wit's end here.  I had three scripts working beautifully, and then overnight they all failed with the dreaded "Service Error".

The error always references `getLastRow` as the offending line.  I've tried adding and removing rows at the bottom of the sheet, removing some of the rows with data in them, unfreezing headers and columns, etc. with no luck whatsoever.  I also tried reverting back to last week's version of the script, long before the failure (first was Monday night), to no avail.

I've done a lot of research and I've noticed most often the thing that fixes these Service Errors is something completely random.  Some people say that this error is caused by memoization on Google's end.  If so, what can I do to fix this?

A huge project is basically crashing and burning because these scripts failed...any help would be awesome.  Thanks.

For reference, one of my scripts (the one that failed first).

```
function timeStamp2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[4];
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
Logger.log(numRows)
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
// Fetch the range of cells
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows,    sheet.getLastColumn());
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
//Logger.log(data)

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];

var schedulingStatus = row[4];
var timeStamp = row[3];
var scheduled = "Scheduled";

  if(timeStamp === '') {
    if(schedulingStatus == scheduled ) {
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(new Date());

    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this only happen on scheduled runs or also when you run it automatically? Are the sheets very large?

Comment: @robin It happens scheduled with a trigger and also manually.  The sheet is on the larger side, but I tried paring down/deleting some tabs and it still gives the error...

Answer (score 2):

Whether this constitutes an 'Answer' I cannot judge, but rest assured you are not alone in noticing the sporadic behavior of certain intrinsic GAS functions – notably a few in common use with spreadsheets to append new rows or locate the last row/column of data – which has plagued my own code and others' due to extremely long execution times, often as high as 20 seconds per instance!

I insist there must be a hidden timing flaw in `getLastRow()`, as shown below. The problem now routinely leads to Timeouts in my workflow and generates frequent failures and **Service error: Spreadsheets** messages.

For example, if you run the following code function every minute (via a timed Trigger)...

```
    function getLastRow_TEST() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("getLastRow_TEST");
      var timeBegin = Date.now();
      var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
      var timeEnd = Date.now();
      var range = sheet.getRange("A" + nextRow + ":B" + nextRow);
      var timeElapsed = (timeEnd - timeBegin) / 1000;
      range.setValues([[nextRow - 1, timeElapsed]]);
    }
```

...on your test Spreadsheet, containing a sheet named '**getLastRow_TEST**', you will soon notice clustered delays (> 1 sec.), as shown in the resulting data (collected at 10:55am on Monday 6/13/2016), but with no discernible pattern of occurrence:

```
    TEST #  SECONDS
    1       0.041
    2       10.242 *
    3       10.256 *
    4       5.194 *
    5       0.055
    6       0.178
```

NOTE: This testing was performed with an otherwise pristine (empty) spreadsheet, with no other code running, no timed Triggers, nor script locking active.

I am attempting to submit this issue as a bug report on Google's issues tracker, but felt compelled to share my experience with you here (I posted elsewhere on SO about this glitch).

Comment: Thanks for the solidarity in dealing with this issue.  I've had to just create whole new sheets and new scripts since I can't seem to solve it.  Adding returns in my script or writing it in a way that eliminates long function loops seems to help preventing the issue, which supports your theory relating to execution times.  Here's hoping Google does something about it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you counting your array positions correctly?

```
ss.getSheets()[4]
```

means it's the fifth sheet. I also noticed that although you initialise timeStamp as the value in the fourth column of row:

```
var timeStamp = row[3]
```

later on you:

```
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(new Date())
```

in the third column of the row. ie row[3] is one cell to the right of sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).

Comment: That is all correct - I've used logger to verify as well and the problem persists. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a script I wrote.

It gave Service Error: Spreadsheets said the problem was with the line containing `getLastRow`.

My fix ended up making sure there was at least one row at the bottom without any data. Haven't had a problem since.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently.

My attempts to fix would be:

1. Try to replace `getLastRow` with [`getMaxRows`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getMaxRows()) — get the last
   row of a sheet
2. Try to use the construction like:
   `sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();` → assuming my data range starts
   at row #1, the result should be the same.